# How to omit parameters in a REST call

Tags: groovy, automation, ready-api

For my automation project I will have a lot of testsuites and testcases with a lot of combinations. For this I'm using ReadyAPI to do the automation.

For each testsuite I've entered the necessary parameters to be able to use in each testcase. In ReadyAPI you do that in tab "Projects" on your created webservice.

Now, not all parameters will be filled in for a particular testcase whereas the REST request will send anyways all the parameters as emtpy string.

For this project this is harmful, as an empty string could give an answer, and that isn't what I'm looking for.

For example:

Testsuite parameters: name, cbe_number, country, municipality, neighbours, street, housenumber, po_box

Testcase: Search company on name

For this testcase only parameter 'name' will be filled in, but when I send the request, all other parameters are also filled in in the URL. 
My question was: "How can I, per testcase, omit the other parameters please?"

The answer was that this isn't possible for the moment but there should be a work arround. Though it doesn't work for me. I've followed the steps that the Kudoed moderator has given me, with 1 step that I missed, but even after fixing this step, the GroovyScript is still given an error message after debuggin.
"wslite.rest.RESTClientException: URL and Method are required
error at line:26"

This is the GroovyScript:

```
import wslite.rest.*

def getMap = { key ->
    def props = context.testCase.propertyNames.findAll { it.startsWith(key)}
    def result = [:]
    props.each { result [it.split('_').last()] = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(it) }
    result
}


def headerz = getMap('HEADER')
def queriez = getMap('QUERY')
log.info headerz
log.info queriez
def serviceHost = context.expand('${#Project#SERVICE_HOST_PORT}')
def urlPath = '/agents/organizations'

def client = new RESTClient(serviceHost)
def response = client.get(path: urlPath,
                     accept: ContentType.JSON,
                     query : queriez,
                     headers: headerz
                     )
assert response.statusCode == 200
log.info groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(response.text)
```

I've installed the jar package wslite in the SmartBear>bin>ext folder, I've created a new webservice with an Endpoint, I've added parameters HEADER_[value] and QUERY_[value] on testcase level with their values, but still I've got errormessages.....
Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code works fine:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.3')
import wslite.rest.*

def client = new RESTClient('https://httpbin.org:443')
def response = client.get([
        path: '/get',
        accept: ContentType.JSON,
        query : [aaa:1,bbb:2],
        headers: [ccc:'333',ddd:'444']
    ])
assert response.statusCode == 200
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(response.text)
```

however for the following code

```
def client = new RESTClient('')
```

you'll get exception `wslite.rest.RESTClientException: URL and Method are required`

so, it means that `context.expand('${#Project#SERVICE_HOST_PORT}')` gives you an empty or non-valid value

Comment: daggett,  yes indeed, that is the error message. What do you suggest please?

Comment: check if #Project#SERVICE_HOST_PORT parameter defined

Comment: Hi daggett, sorry for the late response: I think it worked, but I always get an internal server error (500) whilst the swaggerUI is reachable and up and running. Any idea why please? My architect already had a look at it and he says this has to do with ReadyAPI.  Cheers.